# Spring data mongo using CoroutineCrudRepository

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use new Spring data reactive approach using CoroutineCrudRepository in a Kotlin project.

Github repository link: https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-data-CoroutineCrudRepository-test

This is my application's code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication



data class  PersonDto(val age: Int, val name : String)

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
class PersonController (val personService: PersonService)
{
    
    @GetMapping
    suspend fun getPersons() = personService.getAll()

    @PostMapping
    suspend fun savePerson(@RequestBody personDto: PersonDto) = personService.save(personDto)
    
}

interface PersonService {
    suspend fun getAll(): Flow<Person>
    suspend fun getById(id: String): Person?
    suspend fun save(personDto: PersonDto): Person
}

@Service
class PersonServiceImpl (private val personRepository: PersonRepository ) : PersonService
{
    
    override suspend fun getAll(): Flow<Person> {
        return personRepository.findAll()
    }

    override suspend fun getById(id: String): Person? {
        return personRepository.findById(id)
    }

    override suspend fun save(personDto: PersonDto): Person
    {
        return personRepository.save(personDto.convertToPerson())
    }

}

fun PersonDto.convertToPerson() =
    Person(
        name = name,
        age = age
    )


@Document
data class Person (@Id val id: String? =  null, val age: Int, val name : String)

@Repository
interface PersonRepository: CoroutineCrudRepository<Person, String>



fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

When I try to start my Spring boot project

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository.count(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); Reason: No property 'count' found for type 'Person'; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'count' found for type 'Person'
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
```

I don't know why "No property 'count' found for type" error is thrown. Which would be the way to be able to use CoroutineCrudRepository using Spring data mongo repository?

Comment: I am also facing this issue, but with a Postgress DB and org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.6.4. There is something weird going on with the count() method of CoroutineCrudRepository. If I change this to CrudRepository, everything works fine.